# What's the notation for "up to an affine transformation"?

Tags: notation

Suppose y=ax+b, where a and b are constants. This is to say that y is equal to x up to an affine transformation. Is there any notation to express the relationship between y and x that is similar to $\propto$ (the notation for proportional to)? Thanks!

Comment: This function actually isn't linear in the sense that transformations are linear: consider that for any linear transformtion $T(x), 0T(x) = 0 \to T(0) = 0,$ but here $y(0) = b.$

Comment: @StephenDonovan Thanks! You are right, the one I asked about is called affine transformation, right?

Comment: Affine transformations are  often used is dimension $>1$.

Comment: You can transform any given point to any other given point by an affine transformation. So all points are equal up to affine transformation, so that's not an interesting enough notion to warrant a unique symbol.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos The same applies to “proportional” if you apply it to individual points (except for $0$). But $y \propto x$ does not mean that the *point* $y$ is proportional to $x$ but rather that $x$ and $y$ are functions and $y(t) = \alpha x(t)$ for all $t$, where $\alpha$ is independent of $t$. The same concept can be applied to “up to an affine transformation” and it is not trivial in that case. Alas, I know of no special notation for this.

Comment: @markvs Thanks! Agree. I'm actually considering the relationship between two random variables, i.e., two measurable functions.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Thanks! It's very helpful. Sorry for my unclear question, the y and x are actually random variables in my problem. So each of them is a function.

Comment: @EikeSchulte Thank you! It's very helpful!